# Why is least squares temporal difference (LSTD) method more sample efficient compared to Temporal difference (TD) for value function approximation

Tags: reinforcement-learning, temporal-difference

I am trying to understand how LSTD works in value function approximation. I am reading the preliminaries of this [paper](https://www.aaai.org/Papers/AAAI/2006/AAAI06-057.pdf). I sort of understand how the LSTD method differs from TD learning.

In **TD** learning, the gradient update is applied to $V_{\theta}(s_t)$ to minimise the TD error for each sample $\delta_t(V_{\theta}) = r_t + V_{\theta}(s_{t+1} ) - V_{\theta}(s_t)$.

In **LSTD** the gradient update is applied to find a $\theta$ that minimises the sum of temporal difference updates over all the sample of experiences.

In the paper linked above, they define $\mu_t(\theta) = \phi(s_t)\delta_t(V_{\theta})$ which is the gradient descent update that would be applied to increment $\theta$ at every time step. $\theta_{t+1} \leftarrow \theta_t + \alpha \mu_t(\theta)$

In LSTD,
$$\mu_t(\theta) = \sum_{i=1}^t \mu_i(\theta)$$

which is equivalent to the sum of gradient updates for each sample of experience up to time $t$. The LSTD update tries to find a $\theta$ such that the sum of these gradient updates for each time step equals 0.

Relating to this I have 2 questions.

1. $\mu_t(\theta)$ is the sum of gradient updates over all the samples up to time $t$. Why would the $\theta$ that causes the sum of these gradient updates to be 0 lead to the correct value function approximation ?
2. How is doing LSTD more sample efficient than TD. In LSTD, we are only using all samples up to time $t$ in doing the gradient update for $\theta$ and for TD, we are updating $\theta$ every sample. But that does not mean being more sample efficient.